# Get total count of included items in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've an object 'totalItems' which has keys containing numbers as values.

I've an array called 'exluded' which contains strings of keys that are supposed to be excluded when doing the count.

Now, since my 'excluded' array contains 'B' & 'C', while counting the sum of values of the object, I shouldn't include 'B' & 'C'.

Hence, my output should be : value of A + value of D = 2 + 1 = 3.

How do I achieve this?

```js
function getData() {
 var totalItems = {
  'A': 2,
  'B': 1,
  'C': 1,
  'D': 1
 } 
 var excluded = ['B', 'C'];
 // console.log(Object.keys(passengers));   
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getData()">Get data</button>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Just in case if you are new to Javascript and cannot help yourselves out, I'll better suggest start with the basics and then approach this problem as this is a trivial problem and once you are comfortable with syntax approach this again

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this, if you want to use `Object.keys` :

```js
function getData() {
 var totalItems = {
  'A': 2,
  'B': 1,
  'C': 1,
  'D': 1
 } 
 var excluded = ['B', 'C'];
  
  const sum = Object
    .keys(totalItems)
    .filter(key => !excluded.includes(key))
    .reduce((sum, key) => sum + totalItems[key], 0);
  
  console.log(sum);   
}
```